# Any benefit of using 'return' vs 'break' in a Switch-Case construct?

Tags: c, embedded

I am studying a code for a 32-bit MCU in which I see a Switch-case construct that only uses 'return' inside each case instead of the usual 'break' statement. What can be th benefit of doing it like this?

Normally all Switch-case statements use break to exit from it. But if 'return' is used instead of 'break' will it give faster code or smaller code or maybe some other benefit of doing it in this way?

```
switch (adv_mode)
{
    case BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED_HIGH_DUTY:
        if (   (p_advertising->adv_modes_config.ble_adv_directed_high_duty_enabled)
            && (!p_advertising->adv_modes_config.ble_adv_extended_enabled)
            && (peer_addr_is_valid))
        {
            return BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED_HIGH_DUTY;
        }
        // Fallthrough.

    case BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED:
        if ((p_advertising->adv_modes_config.ble_adv_directed_enabled) && peer_addr_is_valid)
        {
            return BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED;
        }
        // Fallthrough.

    case BLE_ADV_MODE_FAST:
        if (p_advertising->adv_modes_config.ble_adv_fast_enabled)
        {
            return BLE_ADV_MODE_FAST;
        }
        // Fallthrough.

    case BLE_ADV_MODE_SLOW:
        if (p_advertising->adv_modes_config.ble_adv_slow_enabled)
        {
            return BLE_ADV_MODE_SLOW;
        }
        // Fallthrough.

    default:
        return BLE_ADV_MODE_IDLE;
}
```

I expect that bit 'return' and 'break' will give the same results. So it is just a preference which is used by a programmer.

Comment: IMO `return` makes clear that there is nothing more to do after the `switch` block while `break` means select this condition and there are more tasks to do after the `switch` block.

Comment: IMHO the main benefit is that you don't have to fetch the code for "what happens next" when you early return. But this is a sensitive subject.... (sadly)

Comment: But the return value differ. The effect of `break` is just to break from the switch and _continue with the function_, the effect of `return` is to return from the function, with the value. These are different things... I believe the code here uses return because it "looks more readable" (this is subjective), compared to using a variable, storing the value to return, and calling return later.

Comment: If there is a benefit or not depends on the problem to solve. So as it stands the question is either too broad, or option based. So it is off-topic in any case.

Comment: Personally I'd use `break` unless I had good reason to use `return`, not the other way round.

Comment: As you do not show us what happens before and after that `switch` no one can answer if the result is same or not. In every function that does not immediately return after a `switch`, the effect will be totally different and far from being "just a preference".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`return`** leaves the function the `switch` is in and jumps back to its caller.

**`break`** leaves just the `switch` and the next statement after it will be executed.

In the shown case the function returns some kind of mode. If `break` had been used a variable for this result had to be set and returned at the end of the function. Sometimes developer find this too much to write.

Comment: Some other times some other developers find a function that has one single entry point, so should not have more that one `return` statement.

Comment: *a function that has one single entry point, so should not have more that one `return` statement*  That's cargo-cult programming.  Force-fitting an algorithm into a preconceived number of `return` statements despite making code more complex, less readable, and harder to maintain?

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage or disadvantage in terms of performance. There is no reason to believe that a version containing a temporary result variable and `break` would produce any different machine code.

However, it needs to be mention that this is just a very ugly way of writing an `if` chain. `switch` fallthrough is incredibly bad and dangerous practice and should never be used. This code should be rewritten to be more robust and readable both:

```
if(adv_mode == BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED_HIGH_DUTY && this && that)
{
  result = BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED_HIGH_DUTY;
}
else if(...)
{
  result = BLE_ADV_MODE_DIRECTED;
}
```

Or in case the constants are adjacent enums from 0 to *n*, simply replace the whole thing with:

```
return check(p_advertising)[adv_mode];
```

where `check` is an array of function pointers, each pointing at a function containing the mode-specific checks. (This will come with function call overhead but far less branches.)